# Why does gevent.sleep(0) not yield, requiring a non-zero value to do so?

Tags: python, uwsgi, gevent

Trying to test if my uWSGI->py2.7->Flask->gevent app is serving requests concurrently.

Many guides say 'gevent.sleep(0)' is what you need to do to have your 'thread' yield. 
 For my situation, it is not working.  After much trial and error, I realized I had to put a non-zero sleep value to make my running greenlet to yield.

This tip in the actual gevent.sleep docs actual does explain how a non-zero value works, and it makes sense to me why it does work:

> Tip In the current implementation, a value of 0 (the default) means to yield execution to any other runnable greenlets, but this greenlet may be scheduled again before the event loop cycles (in an extreme case, a greenlet that repeatedly sleeps with 0 can prevent greenlets that are ready to do I/O from being scheduled for some (small) period of time); a value greater than 0, on the other hand, will delay running this greenlet until the next iteration of the loop.

What I do *not* understand, is why sleep(0) does *not* work, and what sleep(0) is actually doing.  On sleep(0), what does gevent do to decide what greenlet to context switch to?  And if it isn't intended or able to switch on sleep(0), what is the point of that default and why do so many guides on the internet say to do it that way?

Comment: Did you had a look a the tutorial: https://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial (Section: Synchronous & Asynchronous Execution) ?

Comment: I have seen that... it is a very good tutorial.  It doesn't address that specific question though.  I'm used to threading in C++/Java and am just just trying to understand the intricacies of pythons threading workarounds, which are ironically more complicated than true threading.  This is just a specific detail I'd like to understand better.